# 選ぶ or 決める for ”First Choose a color"

Tags: translation, word-choice

I'm writing instructions for how to make a request, but I'm not sure which to use?

> 先ずは色を決めて下さい。

Or

> 先ずは色を選んで下さい。

Are there any differences? Or am I completely off?

Comment: A request for what?  Is this technology related?  And what is the demographic of your audience?

Comment: If I take an art request, I'd like someone to choose a color, and I can make a monochrome picture using that color. Is that too vague?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be interchangeable in some case though.

先ずは色を決めて下さい。It's like you are asking to select the background color of artwork in advance.  To select one color in high-confidence. It sounds much more decisive.

先ずは色を選んで下さい。It's like you are simply asking to pick up one color in advance. It can be a flexible request. You are not requesting one color controls its artwork.

Edit:
Sorry. A big mistake.
deterministic -> decisive.

Comment: @macraf  Thanks. Confused. It’s decisive.

Answer (score 2):

> A. 先ずは色を決めて下さい。
>   Or
>   B. 先ずは色を選んで下さい。

I agree with kimi Tanaka's answer (+1).

Threfore, it depends on the application.

If there are many things to decide and rush to finish all the decisions, "A" would be better. In this case backtracking at each option is not much expected.
On the other hand, there is time to spare when using "B", and there is a nuance that it is highly tolerable for the selection, so in some cases it is also permissible to select again.